# Transform XML using XSL template

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform the following XML structure input using XSL template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<ECG>
  <R000>4</R000>
  <R001>
    <A01>R1 A1 Data</A01>
    <A02>R1 A2 Data</A02>
    <A03>R2 A3 Data</A03>
  </R001>
  <R002>
    <A01>R2 A1 Data</A01>
    <A02>R2 A2 Data</A02>
    <A03>R2 A3 Data</A03>
  </R002>
  <R003>
    <A01>R3 A1 Data</A01>
    <A02>R3 A2 Data</A02>
    <A03>R3 A3 Data</A03>
  </R003>
  <R004>
    <A01>R4 A1 Data</A01>
    <A02>R4 A2 Data</A02>
    <A03>R4 A3 Data</A03>
  </R004>
</ECG>
```

Tag `R000` determines how many `RXXX` registers the XML will contain. The idea is to transform the XML using the XSL to the following output. In this case, I apply it to four `R000` values. The idea is to use a random number in input, so it will handle n registers. `A01`, `A02`, `A03` tags will always be present. Just the `RXXX` number is variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<input>
  <data>
    <registry DATA1 = "R1 A1 Data" DATA2 = "R1 A2 Data" DATA3 = "R1 A3 Data"/>
    <registry DATA1 = "R2 A1 Data" DATA2 = "R2 A2 Data" DATA3 = "R2 A3 Data"/>
    <registry DATA1 = "R3 A1 Data" DATA2 = "R3 A2 Data" DATA3 = "R3 A3 Data"/>
    <registry DATA1 = "R4 A1 Data" DATA2 = "R4 A2 Data" DATA3 = "R4 A3 Data"/>
  </data>
</input>
```

I have tried following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="input" >
     <xsl:element name="data" >
       <xsl:element name="registry" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA1">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R001/A01"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA2">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R001/A02"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA3">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R001/A03"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="registry" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA1">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R002/A01"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA2">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R002/A02"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA3">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R002/A03"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="registry" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA1">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R003/A01"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA2">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R003/A02"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA3">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R003/A03"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="registry" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA1">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R004/A01"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA2">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R004/A02"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="DATA3">
          <xsl:value-of select="ECG/R004/A03"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think it's not the best way to do that! Because there will be unknown`RXXX` number of tags. Any idea? I have thinked about loop cycle, but it seems is not possible here. Thanks

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I'm having trouble using XSL. Think I need For loop for getting RXXX values. I wasn't able to do that! Thanks

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Just eddited post! I attached my attempt to do that!! Thanks a lot! Your help is very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSL 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ECG">
    <input>
        <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::R000)][position() &lt;= current()/R000]"/>
        </data>
    </input>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <registry DATA1="{A01}" DATA2="{A02}" DATA3="{A03}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @SergioDavidRomero Which part needs explaining? It simply takes a list of all elements that are children of ECG, except `R000", and cuts it off at the position indicated in `R000".

Comment: No, it's just XSLT/XPath.